# Bootstrap-4 typeahead.js change color of the autocomplete text

Tags: bootstrap-4, typeahead.js

I would like to change the color of the auto complete text from black to Grey.
The black text is quite confusing because it seems as part of the input.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeahead.js` creates an additional input field with the classes `.typeahead .tt-hint` to display the hinted value at the place of the original input. So, to override the color, you can actually use the css selectors as below.

```
.typeahead.tt-hint {
    color: lightgrey;
}
```